# Using EF7 & C#, Adding Existing Items to Lists Contained in a Class Throws a Duplicate Key Exception

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I'm experiencing an odd problem using EF7 while updating complex classes where any additions to a list property using data already in the database throws a duplicate key exception. . Here's an example:

```
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class Entity
    {
        public Guid TenantID {get; set;}  // Part of PK
        public Guid OwnerID  {get; set;}
        public Guid EntityID {get; set;}  // Part of PK

        [NotMapped]
        public IdentityKey IdentityKey
        {
            get
            {
                return new()
                {
                    TenantId = TenantID,
                    OwnerId = OwnerID,
                    EntityId = EntityID,
                    Name = EntityReferenceName
                };
            }

            set
            {
                TenantID = value.TenantId;
                EntityID = value.EntityId;
                OwnerID = value.OwnerId;

                if (OwnerID == Guid.Empty)
                {
                    OwnerID = TenantID;
                }

                if (EntityID == Guid.Empty)
                {
                    EntityID = Guid.NewGuid();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [Table("Patients")]
    public class Patient : Entity
    {
        public Patient()
        {
            MetaType = nameof(Patient);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Normalized patient
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"> </param>
        public Patient(IdentityKey key) : base(key)
        {
            MetaType = nameof(Patient);
        }

        public string? PrimaryPatientIdentifier { get; set; }
        public string? AlternatePatientIdentifier { get; set; }

        // Override Location address info with patient's
        public bool UsePatientInfo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public PersonName? Name { get; set; } = new();

        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public List<string> Languages { get; set; } = new();  // en-EN, pl-PL, ...
        public DateTimeOffset BirthDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeceased { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset DeceasedDate { get; set; }
        public byte[]? Photo { get; set; }
        public string? NursingStation { get; set; }
        public string? Floor { get; set; }
        public string? Room { get; set; }
        public string? Bed { get; set; }

        public PatientCare? PatientCare { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset AdmissionDate { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset DischargeDate { get; set; }

        public List<Address>? Addresses { get; set; } = new();
        
        public List<Observation>? Observations { get; set; } = new();
        public List<Diagnosis>? Diagnoses { get; set; } = new();
        public List<Prescription> Prescriptions { get; set; } = new();
        public List<Treatment> Treatments { get; set; } = new();
        public List<PatientPractitioner>? Practitioners { get; set; } = new();
        public List<Location>? Locations { get; set; } = new();
        public List<ContactMethod>? ContactMethods { get; set; } = new();

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifiers - list of ids from Hl7-Fhir
        /// </summary>
        public List<Identifier> FhirIdentifiers { get; set; } = new();

        /// <summary>
        /// Primary spoken language
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public string? PrimaryLanguage
        {
            get => Languages[0];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Current facility if proper
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public Location? PrimaryFacility
        {
            get => Locations?.FirstOrDefault(l => l.LocationType == LocationType.NursingHome);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Primary pharmacy
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public Location? Pharmacy
        {
            get => Locations?.FirstOrDefault(l => l.LocationType == LocationType.RetailPharmacy);
        }

        [NotMapped]
        public Practitioner? PrimaryPractitioner
        {
            get => Practitioners?.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Relationship == PractitionerRelationship.Primary)?.Practitioner;
        }

        [NotMapped]
        public Practitioner? AlternatePractitioner
        {
            get => Practitioners?.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Relationship == PractitionerRelationship.Secondary)?.Practitioner;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Primary address
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public Address? PrimaryAddress
        {
            get => Addresses?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressType == AddressType.Primary);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The primary phone number
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public Phone? PrimaryPhone
        {
            get => IsNotNull(ContactMethods) && ContactMethods.Count > 0
                    ? ContactMethods?.FirstOrDefault(cm => cm?.Phone?.Priority == PhonePriority.Primary)?.Phone
                    : new Phone(IdentityKey);
        }   
    }
```

The Patient class is included in many others such as Facility, Prescription, Treatment, etc.  Adding an instance using EF7 is simple, well as long as all the data in the lists don't exist in the db already.  The problem is if I add anything that exists in the db to a list, an Address for example where an address might be a Hospital, Long Term Care Facility, Home Address, or some other location a patient might call home, the system always throws a duplicate key exception [PostgreSQL: "23505"].

For example:

```
        [Fact]
        public async Task AddAndRemoveExistingAddressFromPatient()
        {
            try
            {
                // Arrange
                var customerdb = RepositoryFactory<Customer>.GetRepository(Constants.IgnorePartition, RepositoryIntent.DataStorage);
                var customer = await customerdb.GetAll();
                var tenantid = customer.ElementAt(0).TenantID;

                var patientdb = RepositoryFactory<Patient>.GetRepository(tenantid, RepositoryIntent.DataStorage);
                var addressdb = RepositoryFactory<Address>.GetRepository(tenantid, RepositoryIntent.DataStorage);

                var patients = await patientdb.GetAll();
                var addresses = await addressdb.GetAll();

                // Act
                var patient = patients.ElementAt(RandomData.Integer(0, patients.Count() - 1));
                var address = addresses.ElementAt(RandomData.Integer(0, addresses.Count() - 1));

                if (!patient.Addresses.Contains(address))
                {
                    patient.Addresses.Add(address);
                    var ret = await patientdb.UpdateRecord(patient);

                     **==> Always Fails Here / UpdateRecord equates to   
                                            context.Patients.Update(patient); 
                                            count = context.SaveChanges();
                    <==                     return count > 0; **

                    if (ret == false)
                    {
                        Assert.Fail("Address was not added as update failed");
                    }
                }

                // Assert
                var patientcopy = await patientdb.GetByIdAsync(patient.EntityID);
                if (!patientcopy.Addresses.Contains(address))
                {
                    Assert.Fail("New address does not exist in new copy of patient");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Assert.Fail($"Test Failed: {ex.Message}\n{ex.StackTrace}");
            }
        }
```

Note that the repository is a wrapper for EF and the methods are a pass through.

The above example always fails, as does any attempt to add existing data to a list. The Primary key for all of the classes in the system are build with the TenantID and EntityID

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Entity>().HasKey(k => new { k.TenantID, k.EntityID });
        }
```

The Migration builds what looks like the proper FKs and includes the proper references:

```
          migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Patients",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    TenantID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
                    EntityID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
                    PrimaryPatientIdentifier = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                    AlternatePatientIdentifier = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                    UsePatientInfo = table.Column<bool>(type: "boolean", nullable: false),
                    NameTenantID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
                    NameEntityID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
                    Gender = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false),
                    Languages = table.Column<List<string>>(type: "text[]", nullable: false),
                    BirthDate = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "timestamp with time zone", nullable: false),
                    IsDeceased = table.Column<bool>(type: "boolean", nullable: false),
                    DeceasedDate = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "timestamp with time zone", nullable: false),
                    Photo = table.Column<byte[]>(type: "bytea", nullable: true),
                    NursingStation = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                    Floor = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                    Room = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                    Bed = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                    PatientCareTenantID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: true),
                    PatientCareEntityID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: true),
                    AdmissionDate = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "timestamp with time zone", nullable: false),
                    DischargeDate = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "timestamp with time zone", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Patients", x => new { x.TenantID, x.EntityID });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Patients_Entities_TenantID_EntityID",
                        columns: x => new { x.TenantID, x.EntityID },
                        principalTable: "Entities",
                        principalColumns: new[] { "TenantID", "EntityID" },
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Patients_PatientCares_PatientCareTenantID_PatientCareEntity~",
                        columns: x => new { x.PatientCareTenantID, x.PatientCareEntityID },
                        principalTable: "PatientCares",
                        principalColumns: new[] { "TenantID", "EntityID" });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Patients_PersonNames_NameTenantID_NameEntityID",
                        columns: x => new { x.NameTenantID, x.NameEntityID },
                        principalTable: "PersonNames",
                        principalColumns: new[] { "TenantID", "EntityID" },
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });


           migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Address",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    TenantID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
                    EntityID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
                    Use = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false),
                    AddressType = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false),
                    Address1 = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                    Address2 = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                    Address3 = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                    City = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                    District = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                    State = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                    PostalCode = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                    Country = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                    StartDate = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "timestamp with time zone", nullable: false),
                    StopDate = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "timestamp with time zone", nullable: false),
                    HL7AddressCode = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                    CustomerEntityID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: true),
                    CustomerTenantID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: true),
                    LocationEntityID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: true),
                    LocationTenantID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: true),
                    PatientEntityID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: true),
                    PatientTenantID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: true),
                    PractitionerEntityID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: true),
                    PractitionerTenantID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Address", x => new { x.TenantID, x.EntityID });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Address_Customers_CustomerTenantID_CustomerEntityID",
                        columns: x => new { x.CustomerTenantID, x.CustomerEntityID },
                        principalTable: "Customers",
                        principalColumns: new[] { "TenantID", "EntityID" });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Address_Locations_LocationTenantID_LocationEntityID",
                        columns: x => new { x.LocationTenantID, x.LocationEntityID },
                        principalTable: "Locations",
                        principalColumns: new[] { "TenantID", "EntityID" });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Address_Patients_PatientTenantID_PatientEntityID",
                        columns: x => new { x.PatientTenantID, x.PatientEntityID },
                        principalTable: "Patients",
                        principalColumns: new[] { "TenantID", "EntityID" });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Address_Practitioners_PractitionerTenantID_PractitionerEnti~",
                        columns: x => new { x.PractitionerTenantID, x.PractitionerEntityID },
                        principalTable: "Practitioners",
                        principalColumns: new[] { "TenantID", "EntityID" });
                });
```

I just can't get Updates to work.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.  I built something similar in 2016 using EF6 and everything worked fine.

I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious, but for the life of me I can't tell what.  Can you help me out?

I've searched all over looking for a similar situation,but have come up dry.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `Update()`, load tracked entity references, update them, then call `SaveChanges()`. References are all-important when working with EF as this governs whether an EF DbContext understands that a given entity should be updated, or potentially treated as a new entity. If you give a DbContext an entity that it isn't tracking then the behaviour is that it assumes that entity is new and should be inserted, unless you explicitly `Attach()` it, but that can have situational consequences if the DbContext happens to be already tracking another reference to an entity for the same row. This can lead to duplicate data being inserted or exceptions.

`Update` is used for  attaching and updating detached entities. If you are attaching a complete graph of entity and its related entities then you must do the due diligence to check for existing tracked references to replace/modify all the way through the graph. This means checking through the DbSet.Local cache for every entity being referenced.

The Repository pattern you are using to try and abstract out EF will likely just be getting in the way. The DbContext itself serves as a unit of work, while DbSets serve as Repositories. I do actively use a repository pattern and UoW around EF to facilitate unit testing easier than trying to mock a DbContext/DbSet, but the purpose of creating that separation is so that I can test business logic without touching a database, the Repository becomes the boundary. Integration tests involve setting up data scenarios and running end-to-end through the repositories.